# Disable HTML 5 video from loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, src

I have a setup where there is a background video displaying depending on the current weather conditions, shown here: http://pitfarmtennis.co.uk/cms/.

There are 6 different videos, currently the jQuery code to decide which to show just sets them to display:none, **This sadly means all of them still load.**

This is the jQuery that is currently making a certain video play, in this case a sunny video:

```
    /*Day-sun*/
    if((weather.code == "28")||(weather.code == "30")||(weather.code == "44")) {
        $('.home-bg-sun').css("display","inline");
    }
```

One solution I have tried is to set all of the src attributes in the HTML to data-src, and then changing the relevant one to src to fire the video, which hasn't worked to date, but I might have done something wrong:

jQuery:

```
    /*Day-sun*/
    if((weather.code == "28")||(weather.code == "30")||(weather.code == "44")) {
        $('.home-bg-sun').attr('src', $('.home-bg-sun').attr('data-src'));
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="home-bg-sun">
    <video class="home-bg-sun-video" autoplay loop poster="wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/images/home-bg-sun-first_frame.jpg">
        <source id="home-bg-sun-video-source" src="wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/videos/home-bg-sun.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source id="home-bg-sun-video-source" src="wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-9db85e4/library/videos/home-bg-sun.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

PS: I am using Yahoo Weather to fetch weather conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload) attribute on the video element.
You may want to try the `metadata` or `none` value.

But note that this attribute is only a hint for browsers, which are not forced to follow it.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. I am trying to test this my adding this code to try to make the video stop loading:

            $("#home-bg-sun-video-source").attr("autoplay", "false");
            $("#home-bg-sun-video-source").attr("preload", "none");

But it isn't working! The video is still showing - is my jQuery incorrect?

Comment: why don't you set it on the html directly? `autoplay` is by default set to false, you don't need it. And yes your code is wrong, these attributes should be set to the video element (`$("#home-bg-sun-video")`)

Comment: Thanks - this works but there the video still loads when autoplay and preload are off it seems, they just don't display.

So instead I tried to set the src attribute on the "#home-bg-sun-video-source" element, but I can't seem to reference it! The video never loads when I set the src this way. Any ideas please?

Comment: if you do change the `<source>` element's src, then you have to call the `<video`>'s `load()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove "autoplay" attribute from hidden videos, and refactor your hypertext like:

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just tested your solution, sadly however the videos still load, they just don't play.

My aim is to prevent the videos having to unnecessarily load.

Comment: May be you should try multiple video tags with single source each other?

Comment: Sorry @user5285659, could you elaborate please? Not sure what you mean.